# is it possible to to apply mouse/touch events to masks with EaselJs?

Tags: mouseevent, easeljs

Is it possible to add mouse events to a shape mask? I have the mask working, and have animated it in other tests. But now I want to know if masks can be clicked and dragged.

You can see the example here: http://www.webnamehere.com/mask/mask.html

And although Easeljs never never seems to work in jsFiddle, you can also see the code here: http://jsfiddle.net/8kbu3/1/

```
var circle = new createjs.Shape();
var Galaxy;
$(document).ready(function() {


canvasWidth = "1024px";
canvasHeight = "768px";
stage = new createjs.Stage('demoCanvas');
createjs.Touch.enable(stage);
$("#demoCanvas").attr({width:canvasWidth, height:canvasHeight});


    Galaxy = new Image();
    Galaxy.src = "images/galaxy.jpg";
    Galaxy.onload = handleImageLoad;    


function handleImageLoad() {
    GalaxyBitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(Galaxy);
    GalaxyBitmap.x = 0;
    GalaxyBitmap.y = 0;

    containerGalaxy = new createjs.Container();
    containerGalaxy.addChild(GalaxyBitmap);
    containerGalaxy.x = 0;
    containerGalaxy.y = 0;

    circle = new createjs.Shape();
    circle.graphics.beginFill('blue').drawCircle(80,80,50).endFill();   
    containerGalaxy.mask = circle;
    stage.addChild(containerGalaxy);
    stage.update(); 
}   

circle.onClick = function(evt){
    alert('what the F?');
}

circle.onPress = function(evt){
    var offset = {x:circle.x-evt.stageX, y:circle.y-evt.stageY};
        evt.onMouseMove = function(ev) {
            circle.x = ev.stageX+offset.x;
            circle.y = ev.stageY+offset.y;
            console.log("circle X: " + circle.x + " | Y: " + circle.y);

            stage.update();
        }
}
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

To receive an click-event you have to add the circle to the stage (`stage.addChild(circle)`) or to a child of the stage, even if it acts as a mask - in your case it might be better to take a transparent dummy-object as the click-listener.

Comment: This answer is correct. I answered this on the EaselJS community site here, including a modified example.http://community.createjs.com/discussions/createjs/532-is-it-possible-to-to-apply-mousetouch-events-to-masks